# Update a Null array through setState in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

I am using setState to update an array whichh is null on the time of declaration

```
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state={
            editValue:[] 
       };
   }
```

i want this to be null
for updating i am using a function

```
  setUpdate(row){
     this.setState(
     {
      editValue:[...this.state.editValue,{
      Name:row.Name,   
     Classes:row.Classes,
     City:row.City
     }]
     }  
     );
  }
```

in row it is giving the desired value when i console it
i know some code error is there but dont know what is that

i want it to be null For Ex: `editValue:null` during the time of declaration.
cant leave it black like `editValue:[]`  due to the my App. Because on some parts it checks the null value.

Comment: i want to update array in state

Comment: If I understand correct, you want it to be null initially but an array of objects later. You can do that like `this.state = { editValue: null };` and then do `const spreadValue = Array.isArray(this.state.editValue) ? this.state.editValue : []; setState({ editValue: [ ...spreadValue, {...} ] })`